# DES cipher with pyca/cryptography (PBEWithMD5AndDES)

Tags: python, cryptography, pycrypto

To support some legacy application I need to implement `PBEWithMD5AndDES` ([RFC2898 Section 6.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2898#section-6.1)) in python. I know this is insecure, deprecated and should not be used anymore. But this is sadly the requirement I have.

I already have a working version that uses `PyCrypto`/`PyCryptodome` but I would need to introduce [`PyCryptodome`](https://pycryptodome.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) as additional dependency to the project which is something I want to avoid. As we are already using [`pyca/cryptography`](https://cryptography.io/en/latest/) in other parts of our code I'd prefer this library over `PyCrypto(dome)`. However due to the nature of `PBEWithMD5AndDES` I need DES encryption support but `pyca/cryptography` only supports Triple DES (3DES) as far as I understood.

Is there a way to (single) DES encrypt something using `pyca/cryptography`? Basically I need to replace the following usage of `Crypto.Cipher.DES` from with something from `pyca/cryptography`:

```
key, init_vector = _pbkdf1_md5(a_password, a_salt, a_iterations)
cipher = DES.new(key, DES.MODE_CBC, init_vector)
encrypted_message = cipher.encrypt(encoded_message)
```

**UPDATE**:


Thanks to @SquareRootOfTwentyThree I ended up with this:

```
(key, init_vector) = _pbkdf1_md5(a_password, a_salt, a_iterations)
cipher = Cipher(algorithms.TripleDES(key), modes.CBC(init_vector), default_backend())
encryptor = self.cipher.encryptor()
encrypted = encryptor.update(encoded_message)
encryptor.finalize()

def _pbkdf1_md5(a_password, a_salt, a_iterations):
    digest = Hash(MD5(), default_backend())
    digest.update(a_password)
    digest.update(a_salt)

    key = None
    for i in range(a_iterations):
        key = digest.finalize()
        digest = Hash(MD5(), default_backend())
        digest.update(key)

    digest.finalize()

    return key[:8], key[8:16]
```

Comment: Triple DES was defined as it was with backwards compatibility in mind. You just have to use 3 identical keys, so instead of using AB or ABC for DESede (where each letter is a 64 bit DES key with parity) you should use AA or AAA. Let me know if this fixes your problem; I cannot tell if you can somehow use this solution together with password based encryption or that you would have to rewrite most of that.

Comment: That package does support MD5, so at least you have that to build pbkdf1 with.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there a way to (single) DES encrypt something using pyca/cryptography?

Yes, just pass an 8 byte key to `cryptography.hazmat.primitives.ciphers.algorithms.TripleDES`. This will use the same key for each DES transform within triple-DES.

Triple-DES is also known as DES-EDE for Encrypt, Decrypt and then Encrypt. If you use the same key for each then one of the encrypt / decrypt pairs will result in the identity function, leaving just a single DES encrypt.

---

Note that not all triple DES implementations will accept a single key (since single DES is usually present), but this one does:

> The secret key. This must be kept secret. Either `64`, `128`, or `192` bits long. DES only uses `56`, `112`, or `168` bits of the key as there is a parity byte in each component of the key. Some writing refers to there being up to three separate keys that are each `56` bits long, they can simply be concatenated to produce the full key.

although I must admit that you'd have to understand how triple-DES works to make any sense of that text.

Note as well that the implementation of DES-EDE for single DES is currently not optimized, it *will* perform all three operations even if two of them cancel each other out.

Comment: That was easy. I already tried that, but had an error in the KDF function which made me think encryption didn't work. Actually the correct KDF already returned the 8 byte key.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @SquareRootOfTwentyThre, My DES-ECB Example：

**PyCrypto/PyCryptodome**

pip install pycryptodome

```
import base64

from Crypto.Cipher import DES
from Crypto.Util.Padding import pad,unpad

key = "the key"

key = key.encode("utf-8")
key = (key + b'\0' * (8 - len(key) % 8))[:8]
des = DES.new(key, DES.MODE_ECB)


data = "Hello World"

# Encrypt
data_p = pad(data.encode("utf-8"), 8, 'pkcs7')
result = des.encrypt(data_p)
b64result = base64.b64encode(result)

print("Input Key:", key)
print("Pad Data: ", data_p)
print("Encrypt Result: ",result)
print("base64 Result: ", b64result)

# Decrypt
# decrypt_data = des.decrypt(result)
# Or from the base64 format
decrypt_data = des.decrypt(base64.b64decode(b64result))
origin_data = unpad(decrypt_data, 8, 'pkcs7')
print('Decrypt:',origin_data)
```

Result:

```
Input Key: b'the key\x00'
Pad Data:  b'Hello World\x05\x05\x05\x05\x05'
Encrypt Result:  b'\x9c\x93\x85\xe4\xc7?\x87\x157 FuLq\xbe\xd8'
base64 Result:  b'nJOF5Mc/hxU3IEZ1THG+2A=='
Decrypt: b'Hello World'
```

**pyca/cryptography**

pip install cryptography

```
import base64
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.ciphers import Cipher, algorithms, modes
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives import padding

key = "the key"

key = key.encode("utf-8")
key = (key + b'\0' * (8 - len(key) % 8))[:8]

cipher = Cipher(algorithms.TripleDES(key), modes.ECB())

data = "Hello World"


# Encrypte
padder = padding.PKCS7(64).padder()
data_p = padder.update(data.encode("utf-8")) + padder.finalize()

encryptor = cipher.encryptor()
result = encryptor.update(data_p) + encryptor.finalize()
b64result = base64.b64encode(result)

print("Input Key:", key)
print("Pad Data: ", data_p)
print("Encrypt Result: ",result)
print("base64 Result: ", b64result)

# Decrypte
decryptor = cipher.decryptor()
# decrypt_data = decryptor.update(result)
# Or from base64 format
decrypt_data = decryptor.update(base64.b64decode(b64result))

unpadder = padding.PKCS7(64).unpadder()
origin_data = unpadder.update(decrypt_data) + unpadder.finalize()
print('Decrypt:',origin_data)
```

Result:

```
Input Key: b'the key\x00'
Pad Data:  b'Hello World\x05\x05\x05\x05\x05'
Encrypt Result:  b'\x9c\x93\x85\xe4\xc7?\x87\x157 FuLq\xbe\xd8'
base64 Result:  b'nJOF5Mc/hxU3IEZ1THG+2A=='
Decrypt: b'Hello World'
```

Comment: Is there a library to decrypt this b64result, which is the encrypted value, with password? Thanks

Comment: @Yuva use the reverse functions: b64decode,  decrypt and unpad.  I have update it to the answer.